# Watin tests failing in Jenkins

Tags: nunit, jenkins, watin

I would like to incorporate functional testing into my Jenkins job. When I run tests manually with nUnit everything works just fine when I run from Jenkins:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6\bin\nunit-console.exe" /framework:net-4.0 /xml:functional-tests.xml c:\IISRoot\ALAS-QA\ALAS.Web.Test.dll /apartment=STA /process=Separate
```

I get this exception on every single test

```
Test Error : ALAS.Web.Test.TestAddLead.TestAddSingleLead
WatiN.Core.Exceptions.BrowserNotFoundException : Could not find an IE window matching constraint: Timeout while waiting to attach to newly created instance of IE.. Search expired after '30' seconds.
at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateIEPartiallyInitializedInNewProcess()
at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri(Uri uri, IDialogHandler logonDialogHandler,  oolean createInNewProcess)
at FluentAutomation.WatiN.AutomationProvider.getCurrentBrowser()
at FluentAutomation.WatiN.AutomationProvider.Navigate(Uri pageUri)
at ALAS.Web.Test.TestExtensionMethods.Login(CommandManager I, String username, String password) in c:\java\jenkins\workspace\SCI-ALAS\ALAS.Web.Test\TestExtensionMethods.cs:line 40
at ALAS.Web.Test.TestAddLead.TestAddSingleLead() in c:\java\jenkins\workspace\SCI-ALAS\ALAS.Web.Test\TestAddLead.cs:line 33
```

line in which I get this error tries to attach to IE window.

I am on windows 2008 server, with IE9

*Added Friday 3 August 2012*

I've read that this may be the cause of

- Requests for "localhost" will resolve to the IPv6 address of ::1 by default rather than the IPv4 address of 127.0.0.1 and the WatiN tests will fail.

This is not the case, because I'm testing against a public URL not on the local machine.

- IE Enhanced Security Configuration turned on

I've turned this off without any result.

- Missing files Microsoft.mshtml.dll, Interop.shdocvw.dll or Watin.Core.dll

  I have those in my output directory where the tests are run.

Comment: Are you trying to login through URL?

Comment: yes i am trying to attach by URL

Comment: you need to find a patch or registry file for doing this.

Comment: can you point me a little closer @Aura

Answer (score 0):

I am trying info from this SO post [Watin through tfs on windows 2008 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674888/watin-through-tfs-on-windows-2008-server)
this basically says that

> Automated UI tests cannot be run in the build agent running as a windows service since it is not interactive, meaning that it cannot interact with the desktop

so I am planning on creating my own "interactive agent"  by having a bach file that has the nunit call and in Jenkins running it like:

```
cmd /interactive /c C:\workfolder\nunit-test.bat
```